# Kotlin Android Dice roller app: Why after tapping on " Reset " button, it is not doing anything?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a dice roller app. Two buttons are there on the screen, one is " Roll " and another is " Reset ". While clicking on "Roll" it will roll two dices with different random values. Now, I want to set the functionality for " Reset " so that it can populate the empty screen when clicked. I did, but nothing happened after tapping on ' Reset '.

**Here is my code of Mainactivity.kt**

```
package com.example.mydiceroller <br />

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity <br />
import android.os.Bundle <br />
import android.widget.Button <br />
import android.widget.ImageView <br />
import android.widget.TextView <br />
import android.widget.Toast <br />

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { <br />
lateinit var diceImage : ImageView <br />
lateinit var diceImage2 : ImageView <br />
lateinit var diceImage3 : ImageView <br />

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) 


    val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button) 
    rollButton.setOnClickListener{rollDice()} 
    val resetButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.reset_button) 
    resetButton.setOnClickListener{resetDice()} 

    diceImage = findViewById(R.id.dice_image) 
    diceImage2 = findViewById(R.id.dice_image2) 
    diceImage3 = findViewById((R.id.dice_image3)) 


} 

private fun rollDice() { 
    /*Toast.makeText(this,"button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //Display the toast */ 

        diceImage.setImageResource(getRandomDiceImage()) 
        diceImage2.setImageResource(getRandomDiceImage()) 

} 

private fun getRandomDiceImage(): Int { 
    val randomInt = (1..6).random() 

    return when(randomInt){ 
        1 -> R.drawable.dice_1 
        2 -> R.drawable.dice_2 
        3 -> R.drawable.dice_3 
        4 -> R.drawable.dice_4 
        5 -> R.drawable.dice_5 
        else -> R.drawable.dice_6 

    } 

} 
private fun resetDice(){ 
    diceImage3.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_dice) 
} 

}
```

**And here is my code for activity_main.xml**

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
tools:context=".MainActivity" > 

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/dice_image" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="147dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:src="@drawable/empty_dice" 
    tools:src="@drawable/dice_1" /> 

<ImageView <br />
    android:id="@+id/dice_image2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="111dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:src="@drawable/empty_dice" 
    tools:src="@drawable/dice_1" />
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/dice_image3" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="147dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:src="@drawable/empty_dice" 
    tools:src="@drawable/dice_1" /> 




<Button 
    android:id="@+id/roll_button" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/roll_label" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" /> 

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/reset_button" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/reset_label" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" /> 






</LinearLayout> <br />
```

Now, whenever I am tapping on " Reset " button. It does nothing. I am unable to get what I am doing wrong. Please help me to configure it.

Comment: Haven't you connected the button with the corresponding method/action? You could add this line to your `reset_button`: `android:onClick=resetDice` and try again...

Comment: @deHaar I think I did it. If you can see the second onclickListener on resetDice() function. Is that you want to say?

Comment: Oh, yes... You have linked the action. Is the method called at all? And the listener? Could you check by debugging or simple logcat output?

Comment: @deHaar Yep I also think the issue is in method and listener calling. But why, what is wrong in code? I am unable to understand. I debug the code but not able to figure it out.

Comment: What exactly should be happening when the button gets clicked? Currently, only the third dice image will be set to empty dice. Is that what you want?

Comment: Actually I wanted to bring the screen in its initial state that is empty state. Now it's been solved. Correction done in resetDice() function. Thanks.

Comment: Good... I'm interested in the root cause of the problem: What was it?

Comment: Actually, I had to set empty view in resetDice() function for another two Image view objects as well to make the whole screen empty when resetDice( ) function is called on clickListener.